# Calling pthread_cancel on a join'ed thread causes segfault under linux

Tags: c++, pthreads

The following code ends with a segmentation fault on the first call to pthread_cancel but only under linux. Under Mac OS it runs fine. Am I not allowed to call pthread_cancel on a thread that has finished running? Maybe I should not call pthread_cancel at all?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;


void* run(void *args) {
   cerr << "Hallo, Running" << endl;
}   

int main() {
    int n = 100;
    pthread_t* pool = new pthread_t[n];

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        pthread_t tmp;
        pthread_create(&tmp,NULL,&run,NULL);
        pool[i] = (tmp);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        pthread_join(pool[i],0);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        pthread_cancel(pool[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's certainly no point in calling `cancel` after a successful call to `join`, since the thread has already terminated by the time `join` returns.

Comment: Not only is there no point; it specifically invokes undefined behavior. This code is just as bad as `void *foo=malloc(1); free(foo); free(foo);`.

Answer (score 5):

See [POSIX XSH 2.9.2](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09_02):

> Although implementations may have thread IDs that are unique in a system, applications should only assume that thread IDs are usable and unique within a single process. The effect of calling any of the functions defined in this volume of POSIX.1-2008 and passing as an argument the thread ID of a thread from another process is unspecified. The lifetime of a thread ID ends after the thread terminates if it was created with the detachstate attribute set to PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED or if pthread_detach() or pthread_join() has been called for that thread. A conforming implementation is free to reuse a thread ID after its lifetime has ended. **If an application attempts to use a thread ID whose lifetime has ended, the behavior is undefined.**
>
> If a thread is detached, its thread ID is invalid for use as an argument in a call to pthread_detach() or pthread_join().

You may not use a `pthread_t` after the thread it refers to has been joined, or if the thread has terminated while detached. Simply remove the `pthread_cancel` code from your program. It's wrong. `pthread_cancel` is for cancelling an in-progress thread, and has very tricky requirements for using it safely without causing resource leaks. It's not useful for threads which exit on their own.

Comment: That's the correct answer and it is what it is but a reasonable case can be made for it not operating this way from an app's pov.  OP presented a toy case but in real programs it is not always easy to know the exact lifetime of thread and there are a lot of pthread functions that rely on thread ids and are suppose to set ESRCH, otherwise what is the point?

Comment: There's no way for an implementation to make such broken programs happy without permanently leaking memory for each thread that's created. The implementation **may** (not "shall") return `ESRCH` if it detects misuse of an invalid `pthread_t` - for example if it caches thread descriptors for reuse, they would contain a "not in use" field it could use for this purpose. But it's extremely dangerous for an app to rely on this since, once the `pthread_t` is reused, spurious `pthread_cancel` on it would **cancel the wrong thread!!**

Comment: @R..: Your answer is correct, I was searching for this undefined behavior quote and I was not able to find it..left my answer dangling, even previously the UB behavior of pthread_cancel has been criticized and bugs raised about the same have been closed, here's a example. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=151502

Comment: Indeed, this is a really common misunderstanding. Early versions of the POSIX threads specification had serious defects in that they defined `pthread_t` as a completely opaque type (and likewise for other thread-related types), but tried to specify deterministic error-reporting if an invalid/uninitialized object was used. This is at best extremely expensive, and in most cases completely impossible. In any case using a `pthread_t` past its lifetime or using uninitialized objects results in undefined behavior, so POSIX 2008 clarified things by changing all the error "shalls" to "mays".

Comment: I don't see why ESRCH needs to be anything more than "not among what I know to alive right now".  That guarantee is more meaningful than "ESRCH may or may not mean anything" so don't count on it.  Reusing TIDs is problematic but so are PIDs and we seem to get by.  The whole may/shall thing often strikes me as a dodge and in cases like this rubs me the wrong way.

Comment: You misunderstand. On any reasonable implementation, `pthread_t` is **a pointer** to an allocated object in memory that will be freed when the thread's lifetime ends. There is no way to answer the question, for a random pointer, whether it's a pointer to a valid allocated object. The fact that POSIX *ever* specified an `ESRCH` error was a defect in the standard that has been fixed. Regardless, it was **always undefined behavior** to use a `pthread_t` after the thread's lifetime ended, regardless of other text that might have specified error reporting in this case. UB means **all bets are off**

Comment: R, please stop with the **bold**, we aren't having an argument and it isn't necessary.  Reasonableness is in the eye of the beholder.  What is a reasonable trade off to a C programmer may seem like insanity in C#.  While the described pthread_t may be the most efficient it is not the only possible implementation, hence the opaque type.  As a whole I am fine with the linux implementation of pthreads but this particular facet is not cool regardless of whether there is ample ass covering in the specs.  It's like those fake radios in demo cars - this knob would do something if a radio was here.

Comment: No, it's the nature of programming in C. Lots of things are not valid to do and invoke undefined behavior. If you don't like this you should be using Java or C# or something. There's nothing "ass covering" about the phenomenon being discussed here. It's exactly the same as what happens if you use a `malloc`'d block after `free`ing it. `pthread_join` and `pthread_detach`+`pthread_exit` (or equivalent) are the thread equivalents of `free` for allocated memory.