# Why does creating a C++11 thread cause a Fatal Signal?

Tags: android, multithreading, c++11, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I want to create a C++11 thread that runs indefinitely, after a JNI call has been made. Why does this generate a Fatal Signal?

```
#include <thread>

static void teste()
{
    while(true)
        LOGI("IN TEST");
}

JNIEXPORT void Java_blahblah(JNIEnv *javaEnvironment, jobject self)
{
    std::thread t(teste);
    //t.join(); //I don't want to join it here.
}
```

I don't need the C++11 thread to call JNI or anything like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13984169/391161), the destructor of the `thread` will call `std::terminate` if the thread is still joinable at time of destruction.

If you do not want to join the thread, you can fix this by detaching the thread instead.

```
std::thread t(teste).detach();
```