# std::thread thread spun off in object, when does it terminate?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdthread

If I spin off an `std::thread` in the constructor of `Bar` when does it stop running? Is it guaranteed to stop when the `Bar` instance gets destructed?

```
class Bar {

public:

Bar() : thread(&Bar:foo, this) {
}

...

void foo() {
  while (true) {//do stuff//}

}

private:
  std::thread thread;

};
```

---

EDIT: How do I correctly terminate the `std::thread` in the destructor?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13984169/12711

Comment: @kfsone thanks for the comment. Could you specify a bit more on which undefined behavior thread(&Bar::foo, this) is reliant on

Comment: @user695652, it's generally dangerous to pass around `this` (or object members) in a constructor's initializer list. Your object only contains the thread so there's no harm in this example, but if it had more fields, you should be mindful that your thread could start executing before your object is fully constructed.

Answer (score 2):

> If I spin off an std::thread in the constructor of Bar when does it
>   stop running?

the thread will run as long as it executing the callable you provided it, or the program terminates.

> Is it guaranteed to stop when the Bar instance gets destructed?

No. In order to guarantee that, call `std::thread::join` in `Bar` destructor.

Actually, if you hadn't call `thread::join` or `thread::detach` prior to `Bar::~Bar`, than your application will be terminated by calling automatically to `std::terminate`. so you **must** call either `join` (preferable) or `detach` (less recommended).

you also want to call `therad::join` on the object destructor because the spawned thread **relies on the object to be alive**, if the object is destructed while your thread is working on that object - you are using destructed object and you will have undefined behavior in your code.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I don't understand the last part "if you hadn't call thread::join or thread::detach", so in my example above, what happens to the thread?

Comment: if you don't call `thread::join` or `thread::detach` **and** the destructor of the thread starts to run - the entire application terminates.

Comment: well, sort of. "crash" is when the operating system actually kills your process. here, the program itself exits. of course, the standard doesn't really defines the term "crash"

Comment: I see, though I still don't understand how I would correctly terminate my thread in the destructor, yield woudl not work because my thread runs in an endless loop.

Comment: @user695652: it's dangerous to terminate a thread from outside the thread (for example, it's not generally easy or possible for another thread to know whether the thread is holding a mutex) so the widely accepted way to terminate a thread is to somehow signal it to exit.  Your thread's work loop could be something like `while (!exit_thread) ...` instead of `while (true) ...`.  And `exit_thread` would be some object or function that can be used to tell the thread (in a thread-safe manner) that it should clean up and exit.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes and no. Yes, the thread ends, but not by the usual way (killing the thread), but by the main thread exiting due to a `std::terminate` call.

Long answer: The thread can only be safely destructed when the underlying function (*thread*) has finished executing. This can be done in 2 ways

- calling `join()`, which waits for the thread to finish (in your case, never)
- calling `detach()`, which detaches the thread from the main thread (in this case, the thread will end when the main thread closes - when the program terminates).

If the destructor is called if all of [those conditions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/%7Ethread) don't apply, then `std::terminate` is called:

> - it was default-constructed
> - it was moved from
> - `join()` has been called
> - `detach()` has been called

Answer (score 0):

The C++ threading facilities do *not* include a built-in mechanism for terminating a thread. Instead, you must decide for yourself: a) a mechanism to signal the thread that it should terminate, b) that you do not care about the thread being aborted mid-operation when the process terminates and the OS simply ceases to run it's threads any more.

The `std::thread` object is not the thread itself but an opaque object containing a descriptor/handle for the thread, so in theory it could be destroyed without affecting the thread, and there were arguments for and against automatic termination of the thread itself. Instead, as a compromise, it was made so that destroying a `std::thread` object while the thread remained running and attached would cause the application to terminate.

As a result, In it's destructor there is some code like this:

```
~thread() {
    if (this->joinable())
        std::terminate(...);
}
```

Here's an example of using a simple atomic variable and checking for it in the thread. For more complex cases you may need to consider a `condition_variable` or other more sophisticated signaling mechanism.

```
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

class S {
    std::atomic<bool> running_;
    std::thread thread_;
public:
    S() : running_(true), thread_([this] () { work(); }) {}
    void cancel() { running_ = false; }
    ~S() {
        if ( running_ )
            cancel();
        if ( thread_.joinable() )
            thread_.join();
    }
private:
    void work() {
        while ( running_ ) {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
            std::cout << "tick ...\n";
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
            std::cout << "... tock\n";
        }
        std::cout << "!running\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "main()\n";
    {
        S s;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2750));
        std::cout << "end of main, should see a tock and then end\n";
    }
    std::cout << "finished\n";
}
```

Live demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b179f0f9f8bc2e1