# Is there a reliable way to force a thread to stop in C++? (especially detached ones)

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am recently working with threads in C++11. now I am thinking about how to force stop a thread. I couldn't find it on stackoverflow, and also tried these.

- One variable each thread : not so reliable
- return in the main thread : I have to force quit only one not all

and I have no more ideas. I have heard about WinAPI, but I want a portable solution. (that also means I wont use fork())

Can you please give me a solution of this? I really want to do it.

Comment: What is your threading model? C++ does not provide any way to forcefully close the thread unless thread cooperates.

Comment: No. It is impossible to force a thread to stop cleanly. There are sometimes platform-specific ways to do it, but they're always discouraged because they're dangerous. What if you stop the thread while it's in the middle of allocating memory and that corrupts the global heap? What if you stop it while it's holding a lock? Etc. Multi-threading requires careful design.

Comment: At least I could use a mutex, can't I?

Comment: Also, Thanks for fast comments!

Comment: How would you use the mutex? We might be able to help more if you explained your underlying problem. :-)

Comment: This isn't really a C++ question.  Anything you could do with threads in a platform API would almost certainly be a C function.

Comment: @DanKorn  The Posix API is trivially accessed via C++.  Certainly it is possible (and likely) that various Posix methods are implemented in assembly, for performance.  Neither implementation of the API changes  the code nor forces the code to use the API implementation language. Until C++-11, I regularly and trivially used posix threads, pthread_mutex_semaphor, and posix process semaphores in my C++ code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12207684/how-do-i-terminate-a-thread-in-c11

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the biggest problems with force closing a thread in C++ is the RAII violation.

When a function (and subsequently, a thread), gracefully finishes, everything it held is gracefully cleaned up by the destructors of the objects the functions/threads created.

Memory gets freed,
OS resources (handles, file descriptors etc.) are closed and returned to the OS
Locks are getting unlocked so other threads can use the shared resources they protect.
other important tasks are preformed (such as updating counters, logging, etc.).

If you brutally kill a thread (aka by `TerminateThread` on Windows, for example), non of these actually happen, and the program is left in a very dangerous state.

A (not-so) common pattern that can be used is to register a "cancellation token" on which you can monitor and gracefully shut the thread if other thread asks so (a la TPL/PPL). something like

```
auto cancellationToken = std::make_shared<std::atomic_bool>();
cancellationToken->store(false);

class ThreadTerminator : public std::exception{/*...*/};

std::thread thread([cancellationToken]{
  try{
    //... do things
    if (cancellationToken->load()){
       //somone asked the thred to close
       throw ThreadTerminator ();
    }
    //do other things...
    if (cancellationToken->load()){
       //somone asked the thred to close
       throw ThreadTerminator ();
    }
   //...

  }catch(ThreadTerminator){
    return;
  }

});
```

Usually, one doesn't even open a new thread for a small task, it's better to think of a multi threaded application as a collection of concurrent tasks and parallel algorithms. one opens a new thread for some long ongoing background task which is usually performed in some sort of a loop (such as, accepting incoming connections).

So, anyway, the cases for asking a small task to be cancelled are rare anyway.

tldr:

> Is there a reliable way to force a thread to stop in C++?

No.

Comment: So do you mean every method is unreliable?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach for most of my designs:

Think of 2 kinds of Threads:

1)   primary - I call main.

2)   subsequent - any thread launched by main or any subsequent thread

---

When I launch std::thread's in C++ (or posix threads in C++):

a) I provide all subsequent threads access to a boolean "done", initialized to false.  This bool can be directly passed from main (or indirectly through other mechanisms).

b) All my threads have a regular 'heartbeat', typically with a posix semaphore or std::mutex, sometimes with just a timer, and sometimes simply during normal thread operation.

Note that a 'heartbeat' is not polling.

Also note that checking a boolean is really cheap.

Thus, whenever main wants to shut down, it merely sets done to true and 'join's with the subsequent threads.

On occasion main will also signal any semaphore (prior to join) that a subsequent thread might be waiting on.

And sometimes, a subsequent thread has to let its own subsequent thread know it is time to end.

---

Here is an example -

main launching a subsequent thread:

```
std::thread*  thrd = 
    new std::thread(&MyClass_t::threadStart, this, id);
assert(nullptr != thrd);
```

Note that I pass the this pointer to this launch ... within this class instance is a boolean m_done.

Main Commanding shutdown:

In main thread, of course, all I do is

```
m_done = true;
```

In a subsequent thread (and in this design, all are using the same critical section):

```
   void threadStart(uint id) {
      std::cout << id << " " << std::flush; // thread announce

      do {

         doOnce(id);  // the critical section is in this method

      }while(!m_done);   // exit when done
   }
```

And finally, at an outer scope, main invokes the join.

---

Perhaps the take away is - when designing a threaded system, you should also design the system shut down, not just add it on.