# C++ How to know that a thread launched with std::async is running?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdasync

In my application I have a callback and, if a certain event happens, it has to perform certain operations.

```
void callback()
{
  if(event == true)
  {
    // long processing
    performOperations();
  }
}
```

Now, the thing is that the callback is called at a 30Hz rate, while the `performOperations` function can take also ~10 seconds to complete.

After a quick search online I came across [std::async](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async). The strategy I want to implement is that if the `performOperations` is running and a new `event`
happens I want to "kill" (stop nicely) the running thread and start a new one which still launches the `performOperations` function.

So, something like this:

```
void callback()
{
  if(event == true)
  {
    // check if there's a running thread
    if(already_running == true)
    {
      // stop nicely the running thread 
      ...
    }

    // long processing
    performOperations();
  }
}
```

Therefore, my question. Is there a way to know that `performOperations` is still running and kill it?

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible you share a kill, which you check periodically in performOperation, and each time before calling performOperation, you set it?

Comment: Killing a running thread is rarely a good idea. It is very easy to leak resources or leave things in an inconsistent state. It's better to have the thread check regularly whether it should continue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12207684/how-do-i-terminate-a-thread-in-c11