# Is it possible that pthread_cancel() terminates another unintended thread?

Tags: c, pthreads, posix

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7235392/6156470). But after viewing all its answers, I still don't know what kind of safety guarantee one can get with pthread_cancel(). So I would like to ask a more specific question:

Say that pthread_cancel() is called on a pthread_t variable, named my_thread, is it possible that by the time pthread_cancel(my_thread) is executed, the actual thread corresponding to my_thread has already been terminated somehow, and the kernel recycled the value of my_thread for another newly created thread, such that by executing pthread_cancel(my_thread), another unintended thread gets killed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is about race conditions involving `pthread_cancel()`.  POSIX requires that function to be thread safe in the specific, limited sense in which it uses that term, but that doesn't really speak to the question at hand.  The key details are specified in [XSH 2.9.2](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09_02), as @R.. observed earlier in a comment.  In particular:

> The lifetime of a thread ID ends after the thread terminates if it was
>   created with the `detachstate` attribute set to `PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED`
>   or if `pthread_detach()` or `pthread_join()` has been called for that
>   thread. A conforming implementation is free to reuse a thread ID after
>   its lifetime has ended. If an application attempts to use a thread ID
>   whose lifetime has ended, the behavior is undefined.

So an application is permitted to re-use thread IDs whose lifetime has ended, but that's really a side issue because if you attempt to use a stale one then the behavior is undefined, whether the ID has been reused or not.  And of course, one of the innumerable possible manifestations of UB that could ensue in the case described is indeed that a different thread is cancelled than the one you meant to cancel, regardless of whether the thread ID has been reused.

The lifetime of a thread ID ends when the thread it identifies terminates if that thread was created detached, or when it is passed to either `pthread_detach` or `pthread_join` if the thread was created joinable.  It is entirely possible to have a race between that and the execution of `pthread_cancel`.  If the thread was created joinable then you need at least three threads total for that, but if it was created detached then you don't need any other than the one calling `pthread_cancel` and a separate one being cancelled.  Either way `pthread_cancel` is risky.

The accepted answer to the question you linked is misleading, at best, but @DavidSchwartz's comment on it is much more useful, even if I don't think it accurately reflects the specification in every detail.  Here is how I would put it:

1. It is safe to cancel a thread with `pthread_cancel` if one of these cases holds:

   - the thread was created joinable, and it is certain that it cannot have been detached or joined before the `pthread_cancel` call completes, or
   - the thread was created detached, and it is certain that it cannot have terminated, nor have been passed to `pthread_join` or `pthread_attach` (regardless of the success of these calls) before the `pthread_cancel` call completes.
2. It is **not** safe (*i.e.* it risks UB) to attempt to cancel

   - a thread that was created joinable, via the thread ID provided by `pthread_create`, if it is possible for that thread to be detached or joined before the `pthread_cancel` call completes, or
   - a thread that was created detached, if it is possible for that thread to terminate or have `pthread_join` or `pthread_detach` called on it before the `pthread_cancel` call completes.
3. It is unclear whether it is safe to cancel a thread that was created joinable and later detatched, via a thread ID obtained from `pthread_self()` after the detachment, if it is certain that neither `pthread_join` nor `pthread_detach` can have been called on that thread ID before the `pthread_cancel completes.<sup>*</sup>

---

<sup>*</sup>One could interpret the specifications to imply that under those circumstances, `pthread_self` returns a thread ID whose lifetime has already ended, so that the cancellation would definitely produce UB.  But there are at least a couple different contrary interpretations, and under any of those, there is no defined condition under which the lifetime of the thread ID from `pthread_self` ends before the end of the program, leaving it safe to cancel the thread via that ID at any time.

Comment: You're reading the quoted passage wrong. The lifetime of a joinable thread's id does not end when `pthread_join` or `pthread_detach` is called. Only when two conditions have both been met: (1) `pthread_join` or `pthread_detach` has been called, and (2) the thread has exited. IOW the conditions in the quoted text are not `(A && B) || C` but `A && (B || C)`. You absolutely can call `pthread_cancel` on a thread while another thread is already waiting to join it as long as you have a way of knowing (e.g. because you hold a lock that it needs to take before it can exit) that it hasn't exited.

Comment: Perhaps the wording of the standard is particularly poor here, @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE, but *as written* it does not support the interpretation you assert.  Perhaps *in practice*, one may continue to use a thread ID under the circumstances you describe, but that's not supported by the text of the standard.

Comment: Are you claiming there's some reason your choice of precedence for and vs or in the quoted text is right and mine is wrong? Because that's all the matter seems to rest on.

Comment: There is no "and" in the quoted text, @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE.  On further reflection, I think you must want to interpret the sentence as (A after X) (if B or if C or D) as opposed to (A) (after X if B) (or if C or D).  That's a viable alternative, but not more so than the other, grammatically.  I am prepared to accept that the text is even more open to interpretation than the answer already describes, but I prefer the latter parsing because it seems less awkward to me in this instance.  Also, writing code that conforms to the latter parsing is the more conservative choice.

Comment: Indeed I wasn't referring to a literal word "and" but the equivalent logical construct in the grammar. I agree it's grammatically ambiguous, but the way you chose to interpret it does not make sense semantically. The lack of parallel construct in the grammar under your interpretation also suggests it's not the intent; "after...or if" vs "if...or if".

Answer (score 5):

The value can't be "recycled" until the thread is detached or joined. As long as you didn't do either of those things, it's safe to call pthread_cancel, even if the thread already terminated.

Comment: And, of course, there's nothing particularly difficult with storing thread state information (such as whether it has already been cancelled, detached, or joined) along with the `pthread_t`. You can't really share a resource without having safely-shared state information about that resource. Note that passing a `pthread_t` that you are not sure is valid to any function like `pthread_join` or `pthread_cancel` is UB. So anything could happen.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The relevant text is in [XSH 2.9.2 *Thread IDs*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09_02).

Comment: But of course, *yes*, the thread could have been canceled, detached, or joined. In which case, using its ID has undefined behavior.  And that could indeed manifest as canceling a different thread.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I don't see any reason that canceling a thread that's already been canceled (but not detached or joined) would be a problem.

Comment: Yes, @JosephSible, I was a bit overeager.  Whether the thread originally identified by the ID has been cancelled affects the matter only indirectly, via the likelihood of that thread having since been joined.  But that nevertheless leaves this answer incomplete -- the question is asking about the thread-safety of `pthread_cancel`, particularly with respect to race conditions, and this answer essentially says that you don't have to worry about a race if you avoid situations where a race could occur.  That's true, but of limited usefulness.