# unknown failure when pthread_cancel right after pthread_create and pthread_detach

Tags: c, pthreads

I've tested the thread cancellation process, and have a code like this.
It works on my ARM machine, and sometimes works fine, sometimes leads to a segfault, sometimes stuck after created.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

void *t(void *ptr)
{
    printf("in t\n");
    sleep(0.3);
    return NULL;
}

int main() {

    pthread_t p;
    pthread_create(&p, NULL, t, NULL);
    printf("created\n");
    pthread_detach(p);
    pthread_cancel(p);
    printf("canceled\n");

    return 0;
}
```

have no idea which part is leading to the issue(stuck/segfault).

Comment: The [`sleep`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sleep.html) function takes an unsigned integer as argument, which is the number of whole seconds to sleep. Your call is equivalent to `sleep(0)`.

Comment: thanks for reminding, did not notice that...

Comment: The first rule of `pthread_cancel` is "do not call `pthread_cancel`".

Answer (score 3):

I answered this same question [18 years ago](https://comp.os.linux.development.apps.narkive.com/v9xDpbxu/segmentation-fault-in-pthread-cancel-for-detached-thread-with-nptl). It is not safe to call `pthread_cancel` on a detached thread.

Your code has a race condition so its behavior is undefined. If the thread manages to terminate before you call `pthread_cancel`, you are passing an invalid parameter to `pthread_cancel` and that is undefined behavior.

If the code in `main` is managing the lifetime of the thread, do not detach it because otherwise there is no way to ensure the thread ID remains valid. If the code in `main` is not managing the lifetime of the thread, do not call `pthread_cancel` in it. You will never find a safe way to split the difference.

You should think of `pthread_detach` as rendering the thread ID invalid (or "semantically closed" as Glenn Burkhardt put it) and not use it again.

As [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) points out, your `sleep` rounds to zero which makes the race condition more likely to encounter.

Comment: I'd go so far as to say that any use of `pthread_cancel()` is a sign something is wrong with your design.

Comment: hmmm... I found that it'll become more dangerous to manage threads when I need to use pthread_cancel in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, that:

```
pthread_cancel(p);
```

is called before:

```
pthread_detach(p);
```

and you will be fine. More details, why this works, can be found in this answer: [Is it safe to call pthread_cancel() on terminated thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235392/is-it-safe-to-call-pthread-cancel-on-terminated-thread)

Generally, a thread identifier must not be used anymore, after either `pthread_join()` or `pthread_detach()` has been called with it.