# About pthread_kill() behavior

Tags: c, operating-system, pthreads

I have a question about pthread_kill() behavior.

Here's a small code I'm trying out:

```
void my_handler1(int sig)
{
    printf("my_handle1: Got signal %d, tid: %lu\n",sig,pthread_self());
    //exit(0);
}

void *thread_func1(void *arg)
{
    struct sigaction my_action;
    my_action.sa_handler = my_handler1;
    my_action.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &my_action, NULL);
    printf("thread_func1 exit\n");
}


void *thread_func2(void *arg)
{
    int s;
    s = pthread_kill(tid1_g,SIGUSR1);
    if(s)
            handle_error(s,"tfunc2: pthread_kill");

    printf("thread_func2 exit\n");
}


int main()
{
    int s = 0;
    pthread_t tid1;

    s = pthread_create(&tid1,NULL,thread_func1,NULL);
    if(s)
            handle_error(s,"pthread_create1");

    tid1_g = tid1;
    printf("tid1: %lu\n",tid1);
    s = pthread_join(tid1,NULL);
    if(s)
            handle_error(s, "pthread_join");

    printf("After join tid1\n");

    pthread_t tid3;
    s = pthread_create(&tid3,NULL,thread_func2,NULL);
    if(s)
            handle_error(s,"pthread_create3");

    s = pthread_join(tid3,NULL);
    if(s)
            handle_error(s, "pthread_join3");

    printf("After join tid3\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
tid1: 140269627565824
thread_func1 exit
After join tid1
my_handle1: Got signal 10, tid: 140269627565824
thread_func2 exit
After join tid3
```

So, even though I'm calling pthread_kill() on a thread that has already finished, the handler for that thread is still getting called. Isn't pthread_kill() supposed to return error(ESRCH) in case the thread doesn't exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Any use** (*) of the `pthread_t` for a thread after its lifetime (i.e. after `pthread_join` successfully returns, or after the thread terminates in the detached state) results in **undefined behavior**. You should only expect `ESRCH` if the `pthread_t` is still valid, i.e. if you haven't joined the thread yet. Otherwise all bets are off.

Note: By "use" (*), I mean passing it to a `pthread_` function in the standard library. As far as I can tell, merely assigning it to another `pthread_t` variable or otherwise passing it around between your own functions without "using" it doesn't result in UB.

Answer (score 3):

According this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371844/calling-pthread-cancel-on-a-joined-thread-causes-segfault-under-linux) says that passing a signal to an already dead thread (Only if the thread was joined or exited ) results in undefined behavior!

**EDIT**: Found a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371844/calling-pthread-cancel-on-a-joined-thread-causes-segfault-under-linux) which clearly quotes the latest POSIX spec which indicates the behavior to be undefined. Thanks R.. for the correct pointers!

Comment: Only if the thread was joined or exited while detached. It's well-defined if the thread is dead but still joinable.

Comment: The edit is incorrect; POSIX says no such thing. The previous version of POSIX (2001) wrongly gave the impression by saying several functions "shall fail" if "the implementation detects" that the thread no longer exists. Note that no requirement was placed that an implementation must detect such a condition; only that, it it does, it has to use a particular error code. Many implementors and application authors wrongly read this as a mandate that the implementation do something that's generally impossible. POSIX 2008 has fixed all of these issues.

Comment: Also note that both versions (2001 and 2008) were explicit elsewhere (in the general text on threads at the beginning of XSH) that using a `pthread_t` after the end of the thread's lifetime results in UB.

Answer (score 0):

The question [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37217814/how-to-determine-if-a-pthread-is-still-alive) (How to determine if a pthread is still alive) has been marked as duplicate as this question.

But I believe this post just clarifies the behavior of `pthread_kill` and confirms that it does not guarantee the correct behavior if `pthread_kill` is called with the ID which is no more valid. Hence `pthread_kill` can not be used to know if thread is alive or not as if the thread was joined earlier, the ID would not have been valid or would have been re-used and same is the case if its been detached as the resources may have got reclaimed if thread was terminated.

So to determine if thread is alive (question is specifically asked for joinable threads), I could think of only one solution as below:

Use some global data/memory which can be accessed by both the threads and store the return/exit status of thread-whose-status-needs-to-be-determined there. Other threads can check this data/locatin to get its status. (Obviously this assumes that thread exited normally i.e either joined or detached).

For e.g:

```
Have a global bool named as "bTerminated" initialized with "FALSE" and in
the handler function of this thread either make it as "TRUE" before
returning or modify it once it is returned to the caller (i.e where you have
called `pthread_join` for this thread). Check for this variable in any other
threads where you want to know if this thread is alive. Probably it will be
straight to implement such a logic which fits into your original code.
```