# pthread_kill() with invalid thread

Tags: c, pthreads

I'd like to determine if a particular thread 'exists'.

`pthread_kill()` appears to be suited to this task, at least according to its [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_kill.3.html).

> If sig is 0, then no signal is sent, but error checking is still performed.

Or, as my system's man page puts it:

> If sig is 0, then no signal is sent, but error checking is still performed; this can be used to check for the existence of a thread ID.

However when I attempt to pass in an uninitialized `pthread_t`, the application invariably SEGFAULTs.

---

Digging into this, the following snippet from `pthread_kill.c` (from my toolchain) appears to do *no* error checking, and simply attempts to de-reference `threadid` (the de-reference is at `pd->tid`).

```
int
__pthread_kill (threadid, signo)
     pthread_t threadid;
     int signo;
{
  struct pthread *pd = (struct pthread *) threadid;

  /* Make sure the descriptor is valid.  */
  if (DEBUGGING_P && INVALID_TD_P (pd))
    /* Not a valid thread handle.  */
    return ESRCH;

  /* Force load of pd->tid into local variable or register.  Otherwise
     if a thread exits between ESRCH test and tgkill, we might return
     EINVAL, because pd->tid would be cleared by the kernel.  */
  pid_t tid = atomic_forced_read (pd->tid);
  if (__builtin_expect (tid <= 0, 0))
    /* Not a valid thread handle.  */
    return ESRCH;
```

We can't even rely on zero being a good initializer, because of the following:

```c
# define DEBUGGING_P 0
/* Simplified test.  This will not catch all invalid descriptors but
   is better than nothing.  And if the test triggers the thread
   descriptor is guaranteed to be invalid.  */
# define INVALID_TD_P(pd) __builtin_expect ((pd)->tid <= 0, 0)
```

Additionally, I noticed the following in the linked man page (but not on my system's):

> POSIX.1-2008 recommends that if an implementation detects the use of a thread ID after the end of its lifetime, pthread_kill() should return the error ESRCH.  The glibc implementation returns this error in the cases where an invalid thread ID can be detected.  **But note also that POSIX says that an attempt to use a thread ID whose lifetime has ended produces undefined behavior**, and an attempt to use an invalid thread ID in a call to pthread_kill() can, for example, cause a segmentation fault.

---

As outlined [here by R..](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9488124/1347519), I'm asking for the dreaded *undefined behavior*.

It would appear that the manual is indeed misleading - particularly so on my system.

- Is there a good / reliable way to ask find out if a thread exists? (presumably by *not* using `pthread_kill()`)
- Is there a good value that can be used to initialize `pthread_t` type variables, even if we have to catch them ourselves?

I'm suspecting that the answer is to employ `pthread_cleanup_push()` and keep an `is_running` flag of my own, but would like to hear thoughts from others.

Comment: 'I'd like to determine if a particular thread 'exists'.you can't, at least not reliably.  Design so it does not matter.

Comment: It sounds like maybe you're confusing checking whether a "particular thread" exists, in which case that `pthread_t` should be initialized with the value that was returned from `pthread_create()` for that thread, with "any other thread" exists, which is the only semantic meaning I can imagine for you passing an uninitialized `pthread_t`, and which, as you've seen fails... But, as @ThingyWotsit says, you'd be better off re-designing things so that this isn't necessary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've come to a realisation while driving home, and I suspect that many others may find this useful too...

**It would appear that I've been treating the worker (the thread), and the task (what the thread is doing) as one and the same, when in fact, they are not.**

As I've already established from the code snippets in the question, it is unreasonable to ask "*does this thread exist*" as the `pthread_t` is likely just a pointer (it certainly is on my target). It's almost certainly the wrong question.

The same goes for process IDs, file handles, `malloc()`'d memory, etc... they don't use unique and never repeating identifiers, and thus are not unique 'entities' that can be tested for their existence.

The suspicions that I raised in the question are likely true - I'm going to have to use something like an `is_running` flag for the *task* (not thread).

One approach that I've thought about is to use a semaphore initialized to one, `sem_trywait()`, `sem_post()` and `pthread_cleanup_push()`, as in the example below (cleanup missing for brevity).

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct my_task {
    sem_t can_start;
    pthread_t tid;

    /* task-related stuff */
};

void *my_task_worker(void *arg) {
    struct my_task *task = arg;

    pthread_cleanup_push(sem_post, &(task->can_start));

    fprintf(stderr, "--- task starting!\n");
    usleep(2500000);
    fprintf(stderr, "--- task ending!\n");

    pthread_cleanup_pop(1);

    return NULL;
}

void my_task_start(struct my_task *task) {
    int ret;

    ret = sem_trywait(&(task->can_start));
    if (ret != 0) {
        if (errno != EAGAIN) {
            perror("sem_trywait()");
            exit(1);
        }

        fprintf(stderr, ">>> task already running...\n");
        return;
    }

    ret = pthread_create(&(task->tid), NULL, my_task_worker, task);
    if (ret != 0) {
        perror("pthread_create()");
        exit(1);
    }

    fprintf(stderr, ">>> started task!\n");

    return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int ret;
    struct my_task task;
    int i;

    memset(&task, 0, sizeof(0));

    ret = sem_init(&(task.can_start), 0, 1);
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        perror("sem_init()");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        my_task_start(&task);
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
>>> started task!
--- task starting!
>>> task already running...
>>> task already running...
--- task ending!
>>> started task!
--- task starting!
>>> task already running...
>>> task already running...
--- task ending!
>>> started task!
--- task starting!
>>> task already running...
>>> task already running...
--- task ending!
>>> started task!
--- task starting!
```